Using full space on USB for live Kali Linux USB boot
I have a USB flash drive with 128GB of space on it. I downloaded a version of Kali Linux live onto it. It works fine; I can boot no problem.
However, when I run the command sudo apt-get upgrade, I run out of space. It seems like I have roughly only 4GB of total available space.
What am I doing wrong? How do I increase the space of my live boot to use the full capacity of my USB flash drive?
I have tried re-downloading Kali Linux live with persistence, but that does not utilise all 128GB of my USB flash drive. What should I do?

Asking such basic questions strongly suggests you shouldn't be using Kali. Alas, the methods are the same for any distro: Either install it (NOT live or live with persistence; you need to make the live/installation media using another stick, obviously) or use Ventoy, add your ISO and as many others you want and use the remaining space like you normally would. But, honestly and for very obvious reasons, Kali is NOT for you.

What's the  secret magic behind Ventoy? My OS comes with its own disk-writing software. I could have asked this question regarding any OS. It isn't obvious how to use the full space on a live USB download; the version I was installing automatically partitions  it

Nothing secret or magic, just a special implementation of Grub that reads and expands ISOs (and other image files) on-the-fly, from an exFAT partition using the full capacity created by the Ventoy's installer. This is done only once and then any bootable ISO, including Windows, can be copied to it and deleted as many times you want, unless improper use corrupts the data in which case just re-do it.

You just love Ventoy so much. I can already write ISO images to a disk, I just need to reformat it so that I can use the full disk space. The downloader for this dist seems to automatically have one partition size and I can't seem to change it. I want to know IF I can and HOW to change it.

Any Live/installation image (ISO, IMG) file is like that. "Burning" it to an USB flash drive does exactly that as that is the expected behavior when mimicking an optical drive, the size of the image file is the same as the written data partition(s) and any remaining space ISN'T in any way user accessible unless the flash drive is reset. This is very basic knowledge applicable to all similar files and OSes. It's something that any experienced Linux user  is expected to know and nothing short of a Linux expert is expected to be using Kali, end of story.

I'm still going to be using kali, so your little commentary is really pointless and unnecessary. I could have omitted the specific distribution from my question; I can see that mentioning kali is triggering for you.
My question is about partitioning the usb stick, but it seems like it isn't possible to do it the way I want. What I was asking was NOT basic knowledge.

Any mention of Kali here is frowned upon for obvious reasons, as discussed. And what you asked could indeed be about anything, including Windows, and IS basic knowledge for anyone making live/installation media for any OS.

I want you to stop leaving messages, comments and answers.

Get another USB flash drive, flash OS image in there, put it in your PC with your stick where you want Kali Linux and install Kali Linux on your stick like you would do that with a HDD or SSD.
If you don't have another USB flash drive there is probably a way to do that from OS on the main disk, but I don't know about it.

https://superuser.com/questions/1849848/using-full-space-on-usb-for-live-kali-linux-usb-boot/1852023#comment2934503_1849848 It's as simple as that. You may want to [edit] your answer and remove the last paragraph.

Sure, no problem
